# webdriver in selenium opens a new Internet Explorer tab in FireFox

Tags: python, firefox, selenium-webdriver

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://www.google.com')
```

Can someone help me with the above code. I expect this code to open a new tab in Firefox with google.com; instead this opens a new Internet Explorer tab.

Answer (score 0):

Setting up `geckodriver` for `Selenium Python` resolves the issue I think.

It needs to set `geckodriver` path with `FirefoxDriver` as below code:

```
self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path = 'PATH\TO\geckodriver.exe')
```

> - Download geckodriver for your suitable OS from https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases
> - Extract it in a folder of your choice
> - Set the path correctly as mentioned above

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but its not working at all for me. It opens a new tab with this address "https://www.ietab.net/ie-tab-2-introduction"           Python Version : 2.7.9  GeckoDriver :geckodriver-v0.19.1-win64

Comment: Manually set the FireFox as your default browser.

Answer (score 0):

**`IEDriverServer`** and **`GeckoDriver`** both of the **`WebDriver`** variants being/getting **`W3C Compliant`** and **evolving** with each day, it is quite possible that trying to use one of the variants gets hooked to other variant of **`Web Browser`** because of the following reasons :

- Your `Automated Tests` may be running in an environment which is `Manually Intervened` by opening/closing of **`Internet Explorer`** and **`Firefox`** Web Browsers.
- You have a (couple of) dangling instance of **`IEDriverServer`** within your system which needs to be cleaned up.

### Solution :

Here are a few possible solutions for the issue you are facing :

- Always be explicit mentioning the `absolute location` of the **`GeckoDriver`** while initializing the `WebDriver` / `Web Browser` instance as follows :

  ```
  driver=webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\path\to\geckodriver.exe')
  ```
- Within the `tearDown()` method of your `Test Execution` always use **`quit()`** as follows :

  ```
  driver.quit()
  ```
- Before you start the **`Test Execution`** ensure there are no dangling instances of any `WebDriver` variant.
- Incase your **`Test Framework`** leaves any dangling instances add the following `Windows Based Command` at the end of your script to kill the dangling `WebDriver`.

  ```
  taskkill /F /IM <webdriver_variant>.exe /T
  ```
- Periodically **Cleanup** your **`Project WorkSpace`** in your `IDE`.
- Run **`CCleaner`** tool to wipe away all the `OS` chores before and after **`Test Execution`**.
- When you uninstall any `Browser` (any `Software`) from your system use **`Revo Uninstaller`** which cleans up your `Unused Registry Settings` as well.